# Not able to remove or change .p12 certificate in Firebase Console

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I am using Firebase for sending push notification in iOS. After adding my .p12 certificate, Firebase will not update or remove certificate. Update popup is displayed but it will not make any changes.

[image: not able to remove or update .p12 certificate]

Can anybody know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what type of error you found it?

Comment: I did not get any error. remove button is disable.

Comment: If you've already tried using different browsers and the result is the same in the console, I think contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) is the right way to go.

Comment: Yes, You are right may be..