# Remove production APNs

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I have accidentally uploaded my development environment APN where I wanted my production APN .p12 file in Firebase. However I cannot remove it now. There are a button that says "Upload new", which I have tried, but afterwards there are still the old development APN .p12 file.

I have as well tried to delete the iOS app and then install it again, but the keys are still stored under "Cloud Messaging".

How am I able to delete an APN key?

Comment: Seems like a similar issue as this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39590962/4625829). I suggest contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) for this. Cheers!

Comment: For a work around, you can create a new project on firebase.

Answer (score 0):

This same problem happened to me.
However the following workaround does the trick for me:
I have found a workaround to the problem. You try generating a new certificate with a different private key and then try to overwrite the old certificate using that new certificate at Firebase settings.