# The APNs certificate provided does not match the current environment

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

It's my first time to update one app in app store after implementing the Firebase push notifications in the project. I'm trying to upload the "Production Certificate" in Firebase Console, but it gives me this:

> The APNs certificate provided does not match the current environment

I want to make sure that after updating the app users will receive notifications.

Any link with tutorial to update one app in appstore is welcome.

Comment: may be it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359078/remove-production-apns

Comment: thanks mate, do you know is always needed to upload that "Production Certificate" ?

Comment: Test your app on Test Flight first.

Comment: Is same testing .ipa application and flight test?

Answer (score 23):

The mistake I was making was that I was exporting the **"private key"** part of the certificate in **`Keychain Access`** instead of the **"certificate"** part. As soon as I re exported the .p12 using the correct item - it worked.

Please refer to the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37786884/6325474)

Comment: basically he means right click the "kind" -> "certificate" not the "kind" -> private key" of the twister underneath, for some reason on mine the dev version didn't care

Answer (score 4):

The other possibility is:

You are **confusing** the development certificate with Production one in the certificate list of Key Chain Access.

Try to "Export" from the correct one.

This is what brought me here :)